# Class Library (.NET Standard) Missing Something

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I'm trying to create my first Class Library (.NET Standard), but it doesn't seem to support some basic features.

'SolidColorBrush' is not defined.

Same goes for FontFamily and Color amongst others.

My using statements are also showing as not required.

Any ideas ?

Comment: There is nothing "standard" about Winforms, such a program can only ever run Windows desktop.  Not on Linux, not on MacOS, not on a phone, store or web app.  So no point in trying to create a NETStandard library, the regular Class Library project template is just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant points out in a comment, *Windows Forms* related types are not part of *.NET Standard*, they are specific to *.NET Framework*.

However, as long as you confine yourself to [`System.Drawing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) functionality, e.g. `Bitmap`, `Image`, `Color` etc., there is a third-party NuGet package [CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.System.Drawing.v2/) based on Mono that enables you to develop a .NET Standard (version 2.0) class library with drawing functionality that can be consumed by .NET Core applications on Windows, Linux as well as MacOS.

If required, there is also a .NET Standard 1.3 and higher NuGet package [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.System.Drawing), but as far as I understand this package requires a few more tweaks when applied to non-Windows platforms. If possible, I recommend that you use the .NET Standard 2.0 targeted package.

Comment: It would seem that I've misunderstood the concept of .Net Standard.  I was building a UWP app and assumed Standard to mean Universal.  So for a Xamarin Forms project, should I just stick with a PCL ?

Comment: Xamarin (Forms) are able to pick up .NET Standard libraries as well as PCLs. But PCL is being phased out and .NET Standard is the way forward, so I'd go with the latter. And don't expect either to support any graphics or font management.